# decrease a radius by 10% using Index - Jquery

Tags: javascript, math

I have 10 sets of data coming in, and I need to set a radius for the first one to be the largest and then decrease by 10%.

my index comes in like: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5....

I am taking the index and dividing it by 1

```
var radiusTest = 1 / (index);
circleRadius = radiusTest * 100
```

Then I am multiplying it by 100, it is close to what I need but it does not degrade as nicely as I would like.  Having each radius decrease by 10% is what I am looking for, not sure the best way of setting it up?

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery. I've added the `javascript` tag (but left the `jquery` tag on the off-chance someone has a jQuery-specific answer).

Comment: The only way I can think of a jQuery specific answer would be to use jQuery's each() function :/ maybe I don't know jQuery enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are going for something like this:

```
var radiusTest = 1 - index * .1; 
circleRadius = radiusTest * 100
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have a value starting at `100%` and decreasing in equal amounts over `10` iterations, or by 10%.  Here is a way to implement this in JavaScript.

```
var steps = 10,
    step,
    stepSize = 1/steps,
    radii = [];
for(step = 0; step <= steps; step++) {
  radii[step] = (1-(stepSize * step)) * 100;
}
```

The array `radii` should contain:

```
[100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40,30,20, 10, 0]
```

You can mess with the constants to see different steps and step sizes.